# Change the last update date of a file in R

Tags: r, httr

I've written a small function that download a file from my S3 data repository only if the size of the local version of the file is different, to save bandwhich and time.

I would like to improve it to download if and only if the *last update datetime* is different. I can make the check using `HEAD` (from httr package) to get the datetime for the remote file and `file.info` for the local one.

But (as espected) when I download a fresh copy of the file it's going to have the Sysdate as creation/last update time. I need a way to update the datetime of the fresh new local copy with the one from the server *including the potential issue due to different time-zones*.

file.info doesn't seem to be able to **write** file properties.

any idea on how can i do that?

Comment: Taking the timezone issue apart, wouldn't your problem solve itself if your criterion for copying was "the remote file's last mod date is **newer** than the local file's"? Instead of a plain `!=` comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can and even if you could, that approach seems a bit unreliable to me (you mentioned time zones for example).  Instead, I would suggest you rely on a file's `md5sum` (a unique representation of its contents) to tell when it has changed:

```
library(tools)
if (md5sum(remote) != md5sum(local)) file.copy(remote, local)
```

Comment: this would be great idea, but not many servers (and Amazon definitively doesn't) provide a md5 field in the response header. My primary concern is to avoid unneeded downloads...

Comment: Ok. Then what about you just store the info the server is giving you into an R object or separate file, for later comparison?

Comment: yep, it's definitively the best workaround to bake a .md5 file for each file i store on the repo!

Comment: Amazon usually provides an eTag header which contains the md5 hash of a file.